# How do I generate sequence of numbers in logarithmic scale?

Tags: python

How do I generate sequence of numbers in logarithmic scale [0.0001,1]. Is there an inbuilt function in python that takes in range, number of values to produce.

Comment: Take a look at [`numpy.logspace`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.logspace.html).

Comment: @MarkDickinson thanks that worked?. Should I close my question or would you want to answer it?.

Answer (score 0):

I came here as I had the same question. [@MarkDickinson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/270986/mark-dickinson) provided guidance as a comment rather than an answer, so I thought I'd post as an answer what I tried. I took a look at the `numpy` function mentioned and found an alternative I wanted to share. I'm using `numpy` version 1.17.4 with Python 3.7.5.

First import numpy

```py
import numpy as np
```

Then use the [`numpy.logspace()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.logspace.html) function. It will generate logarithmically spaced numbers with endpoints included by default. You will need to decide how many steps you want. In this example, I selected 10 to generate 10 total steps from 0.0001 to 1 inclusive.

```py
np.logspace(start=4, stop=0, base=0.1, num=10)
```

```
array([1.00000000e-04, 2.78255940e-04, 7.74263683e-04, 2.15443469e-03,
       5.99484250e-03, 1.66810054e-02, 4.64158883e-02, 1.29154967e-01,
       3.59381366e-01, 1.00000000e+00])
```

I find the input parameters a bit counter-intuitive as I have to first convert to exponential notation when using the `logspace()` function.

An alternative that makes it easier to just put in the specific range of numbers from the OP is [`numpy.geomspace()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.geomspace.html)

```py
np.geomspace(start=0.0001, stop=1, num=10)
```

```
array([1.00000000e-04, 2.78255940e-04, 7.74263683e-04, 2.15443469e-03,
       5.99484250e-03, 1.66810054e-02, 4.64158883e-02, 1.29154967e-01,
       3.59381366e-01, 1.00000000e+00])
```

End result is identical, however the `geomspace` option allows for the numbers exactly as specified in the OP.